# Knockout not clearing input text

Tags: knockout.js

Knockout not clearing input text value, below are my code

```
<input id="qty0TextBox" type="text" data-bind="value: Qty0TextBoxValue" disabled="disabled" />

var viewTestModel = {
   Qty0TextBoxValue: ko.observable("")
};

viewTestModel.Qty0TextBoxValue("");
```

`viewTestModel.Qty0TextBoxValue("");` is not clearing the text box value, when I use null instead of "" it is clearing.

Comment: try this `<input id="qty0TextBox" type="text" data-bind="value: Qty0TextBoxValue()" disabled="disabled" />` just I added a `()` to the bounded value.

Comment: when are you calling `viewTestModel.Qty0TextBoxValue("");` - feels like there's missing code in your Q

Comment: @HakamFostok, Could you please explain me what () does?...Sorry I'm new to Knockout.js

Comment: @Alex, In one case i need to cleat the text box value, that time i calling

Comment: sometimes there is difference, when you are not using the `()` then you are binding directly to the `observable` but when you use the `()` you are binding to the value of the observable, it make difference sometimes, as I said

Comment: try it, if did not worked please let me now, or you can create fiddler for your case, as it is simple and give me the link of it.

Comment: @HakamFostok, thanks, i will try.

As i said, when i give null insted of "" value is clearing, could you please let me know what is difference

Comment: In the code you show, it is **not** needed to add `()` to the end of your binding. If `null` does not work, but `""` does, there's probably an error in your console because of another dependency on the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `ko.applyBindings` to bind your model to the UI.  Check out [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whe2r00h/1/) for an example.

Comment: I have given ko.applyBindings(), when i give null instead of "", it is clearing

Comment: Please post your full code.  The fiddle above demonstrates setting and clearing observable values that are bound to a textbox.  You could set the observable to an empty string, or null, which would both look the same on the UI (an empty text box) but would differ in your model.